# Strange markup behavior: extra space on UI appears

Tags: html, css

I have ASP.NET application with simple markup related to my case. It looks like:
[image]

And such markup produces following resulting view:

[image]

As you can see there is an extra space between username and exclamation sign. But if I just moving `Label` to the same string as user control it is disappears:

[image]
[image]

I've inspected twice both elements and did not found any paddings/margins (event inherited). Accordingly to CSS both controls hasn't any suspicious settings (maybe I missed some `white-space` settings or something like that, sorry, I am not designed). Resulting HTML looks like:

```
<div id="topMenu_pnlCurrentUser" class="account-user">
      <span id="topMenu_lblHelloUserText">Welcome, </span>
      <a id="topMenu_ctrlCurrentUser_lnkEntityDetails" href="/Application/UserDetails.aspx?user_id=3512">Popov Alexander</a>
      <span>!</span>
    </div>
```

It is definitely line break produces this issue, but I do not know how it could be from HTML/CSS point of view and, what is badder, I do not know how to fix it without move `Label` to the previous string.

Comment: The problem is most probably the carriage return character, or a whitespace at the end of the line. In addition, I tend to use `litteral` instead of `label` control when I'm not creating a `<label>` HTML control, I personally find it cleaner as you most of the time don't use the extra `<span>` added in your case.

Comment: @Bartdude I've tried to change label to literal. The same result.

Comment: Yes, it won't help with your problem, it will just make your rendered HTML more neat... the extra open and closing `span` tags are 11 Bytes , if you use it intensively that will make your pages heavier with no added benefice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the resulting HTML you will notice that there is white space between `Alexander</a>` and `<span>!` (newline and tab). Since both elements are inline elements, the white space between them will be rendered as a space.

Easier solution: remove the white space.

CSS solution (may cause more issues than the ones you are trying to solve): float all span and a tags, add right margin (and use overflow hidden).

```
.account-user { overflow: hidden; }
.account-user span, .account-user a { float: left; margin-right: 8px; }
.account-user span:last-child { margin-right: 0; }
```

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Is setting `display` to `inline-block` for adjacent elements will fix this issue?

Comment: No, inline blocks also behave same way.

Comment: [Here's an interresting article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) on how to fight whitespaces while not changing the indentation of your code to keep it readable.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a need for another `<asp:Label />` just for an exclamation point.

```
Welcome, <StartTrack:UserEntityDetails ... />!
```

That's all you really need.